# What hash (Python 3 hashlib) yields a portable hash of file contents?

Tags: python, hash, portability

I would like to compute the **hash of the contents (sequence of *bits*)** of a file (whose length could be any number of bits, and so not necessarily a multiple of the *trendy* eight) and send that file to a friend along with the hash-value. My friend should be able to compute the same hash from the file contents. I want to use Python 3 to compute the hash, but my friend can't use Python 3 (because I'll wait till next year to send the file and by then Python 3 will be out of style, and he'll want to be using Python++ or whatever). All I can guarantee is that my friend will know how to compute the hash, in a mathematical sense---he might have to write his own code to run on his implementation of the [MIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIX) machine (which he will know how to do).

**What hash do I use**, and, more importantly, **what do I take the hash of**? For example, do I hash the `str` returned from a `read` on the file opened for reading as *text*? Do I hash some `bytes`-like object returned from a *binary* `read`? What if the file has weird end-of-line markers? Do I pad the tail end first so that the thing I am hashing is an appropriate size?

```
import hashlib
FILENAME = "filename"
# Now, what?
```

**I say "sequence of *bits*"** because not all computers are based on the 8-bit byte, and saying "sequence of bytes" is therefore too ambiguous. For example, [GreenArrays, Inc.](http://www.greenarraychips.com/) has designed a [supercomputer on a chip](http://www.greenarraychips.com/home/products/index.html), where each computer has 18-bit (eighteen-bit) words (when these words are used for encoding native instructions, they are composed of three 5-bit "bytes" and one 3-bit byte each). I also understand that before the 1970's, a variety of byte-sizes were used. Although the 8-bit byte may be the most common choice, and may be optimal in some sense, the choice of 8 bits per byte is arbitrary.

### See Also

[Is python's hash() portable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170783/is-pythons-hash-portable)

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at a sequence of bits and not bytes? I'm not aware of any filesystems that allow file sizes to be specified in bits (although I'm only familiar with x86- and ARM-based machines). Either way, you definitely don't want to use the `str` cause that's detached from the file encoding.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm not understanding. How would Python open a file for reading as a sequence of bits and not bytes? If you did need to send a file to a computer with an exotic architecture, how would you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the `hash()` function in Python is not the same as **cryptographic hash functions** in general. Here're the differences:

#### `hash()`

> A hash is an fixed sized integer that identifies a particular value. Each value needs to have its own hash, so for the same value you will get the same hash even if it's not the same object.

> Note that the hash of a value only needs to be the same for one run of Python. In Python 3.3 they will in fact change for every new run of Python

[What does hash do in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585730/what-does-hash-do-in-python)

#### Cryptographic hash functions

> A cryptographic hash function (CHF) is a mathematical algorithm that maps data of an arbitrary size (often called the "message") to a bit array of a fixed size

> It is deterministic, meaning that the same message always results in the same hash.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

---

Now let's come back to your question:

> I would like to compute the hash of the contents (sequence of bits) of a file (whose length could be any number of bits, and so not necessarily a multiple of the trendy eight) and send that file to a friend along with the hash-value. My friend should be able to compute the same hash from the file contents.

What you're looking for is one of the **cryptographic hash functions**. Typically, to calculate the file hash, MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256 are used. You want to open the file as **binary** and hash the binary bits, and finally digest it & encode it in hexadecimal form.

```
import hashlib

def calculateSHA256Hash(filePath):
    h = hashlib.sha256()
    with open(filePath, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read(2048)
        while data != b"":
            h.update(data)
            data = f.read(2048)
    return h.hexdigest()

print(calculateSHA256Hash(filePath = 'stackoverflow_hash.py'))
```

The above code takes itself as an input, hence it produced an SHA-256 hash for itself, being `610e15155439c75f6b63cd084c6a235b42bb6a54950dcb8f2edab45d0280335e`. This remains consistent as long as the code is not changed.

Another example would be to hash a txt file, `test.txt` with content `Helloworld`.

This is done by simply changing the last line of the code to "test.txt"

```
print(calculateSHA256Hash(filePath = 'text.txt'))
```

This gives a SHA-256 hash of `5ab92ff2e9e8e609398a36733c057e4903ac6643c646fbd9ab12d0f6234c8daf`.

Comment: [Binary I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) uses bytes, not bits. I'm not sure what that means for this answer, but it's important to know.

Comment: @wjandrea , RE: "bytes, not bits"---I have edited the question to add a paragraph elaborating on this.

Comment: There is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) of `2048` in `calculateSHA256Hash`. Please add a comment to explain.

Comment: `2048` represents the size of the chunk that's being read. This is to allow the program to load large files without using lots of memory. You can kindly Google `f.read()` or similar words for more information related to this topic, for example, the official [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at `sha256hexdigestFromFile`, an alternative to @Lincoln Yan 's `calculateSHA256Hash`, after reviewing the [standard](http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.180-4) for SHA-256.

This is also a response to my comment about `2048`.

```
def sha256hexdigestFromFile(filePath, blocks = 1):
    '''Return as a str the SHA-256 message digest of contents of
    file at filePath.
        Reference: Introduction of NIST (2015) Secure Hash
    Standard (SHS), FIPS PUB 180-4.  DOI:10.6028/NIST.FIPS.180-4
    '''
    assert isinstance(blocks, int) and 0 < blocks, \
            'The blocks argument must be an int greater than zero.'
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as MessageStream:
        from hashlib import sha256
        from functools import reduce
        def hashUpdated(Hash, MESSAGE_BLOCK):
            Hash.update(MESSAGE_BLOCK)
            return Hash
        def messageBlocks():
            'Return a generator over the blocks of the MessageStream.'
            WORD_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE = 4, 512 # PER THE SHA-256 STANDARD
            BYTE_COUNT = WORD_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE * blocks
            yield MessageStream.read(BYTE_COUNT)
        return reduce(hashUpdated, messageBlocks(), sha256()).hexdigest()
```